# not getting max value more than 999 in MySQL from varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a VARCHAR column in MySQL table which stores only numbers. When I run query

```
SELECT MAX(title_no) as title_no from mytable
```

I get 999 but there are more records in table with value > 999 in title_no column.

I am not allowed to change the column from varchar to int. Please help me to get the correct nuber.

Thanks

Comment: If it stores only numbers - it should be of an `INT` type

Comment: '999' > '1111' - this is just how lexicographical ordering works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MAX(CAST(title_no AS SIGNED))
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one -

```
SELECT MAX(title_no * 1) AS title_no FROM mytable
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like a trick; but it is a MySQL casting behavior. From the documentation - To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, you normally do not have to do anything other than to use the string value as though it were a number. See more information here - [Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try below another way.

```
SELECT  MAX(CAST(title_no AS SIGNED)) AS title_no FROM  mytable;
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(title_no,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) FROM mytable;
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(title_no * 1) AS title_no FROM mytable
```

Comment: Pl see your sql syntax and the second and third query will also not give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to a numeric type, otherwise it will be sorted as a string, not a number:

```
SELECT  MAX(CAST(title_no AS SIGNED)) 
AS title_no 
FROM  mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CAST` here.Because it is treating as a string not as a number.Because you declared as `varchar`

```
MAX(CAST(title_no AS SIGNED))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it will be character comparison as your field is of type varchar. You need to convert it to Integer. See this [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3ed1/5)